# Spring + Thymeleaf not able to find request attribute on input type text

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I've got a seemingly strange issue where I'm getting an IllegalStateException stating: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'custSection' available as request attribute

I've isolated the issue down to the text input with id="sectionsName"... it was previously named "sectionName", but I made it plural thinking it could have been a name collision, but I was wrong.

In any case, when I take out the `th:field="${custSection.sectionName}"` from the input, everything works perfectly and I don't get the 500 error.

What's strange, is that there are other references to the `${custSection}` param that work just fine nested within my `for each` loop... for example, inside the `<span>` where I refer to `th:text="${custSection.sectionName}"`

```html
<div id="sections">
  <div th:each="custSection : ${course.sections}" class="panel panel-primary">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="sectionsName">Section Name:</label>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
          <div class="control-label pull-left label-input" id="_sectionsName"><span id="_sectionsNameText" th:text="${custSection.sectionName}" style="margin-right: 1em;"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="_sectionsNameEditIcon"></span>
          </div>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control hidden" id="sectionsName" type="text" th:field="${custSection.sectionName}" maxlength="60" />
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameOK"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
            <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div th:each="lesson : ${custSection.lessons}" class="panel-body">
      <a th:href="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons/{lessonId}(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id},lessonId=${lesson.id})}" th:text="${lesson.title}"></a>
    </div>
    <form th:action="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id})}" method="post">
      <button class="btn btn-default">Add a Lesson</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>

<form th:action="@{{courseId}/sections(courseId=${course.id})}" method="post">
  <button id="addSection" class="btn btn-info">Add a Section</button>
</form>
```

In my code a `Course` has many `Section`s.

I put a `course` object on the model, and then I'm iterating through each `section` within the `course`.

The only thing I can think of, is that you're not allowed to use a `th:field` reference on any children of a parent object that's on the model.

Comment: Too lengthy html code. Too long didn't read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is indeed a problem with the fact that I'm trying to update children of a parent with thymeleaf.

Here's a post that explains the process: http://justinrodenbostel.com/2014/05/12/part-3-form-binding/

I solved my code by adding the `stat` variable to keep track of the index status in the `for each` loop, then referred to the children via their index of the parent like so:

`th:field="${course.sections[__${stat.index}__].sectionName}"`

Here's a snippet of the full code solution:

```html
<div th:each="custSection, stat : ${course.sections}" class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="sectionsName">Section Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <div class="control-label pull-left label-input" id="_sectionsName"><span id="_sectionsNameText" th:text="${custSection.sectionName}" style="margin-right: 1em;"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="_sectionsNameEditIcon"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control hidden" id="sectionsName" type="text" th:field="${course.sections[__${stat.index}__].sectionName}" maxlength="60" />
          <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameOK"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
          <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div th:each="lesson : ${custSection.lessons}" class="panel-body">
    <a th:href="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons/{lessonId}(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id},lessonId=${lesson.id})}" th:text="${lesson.title}"></a>
  </div>
  <form th:action="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id})}" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Add a Lesson</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.  th:field requires the object you're working with to be directly on the model.  Using the iteration variable, like you did, works, but I think the easiest fix is to give up on th:field entirely and specify all the attributes of your input element.  th:value does not use the same binding as th:field, for some reason (?), and works as expected.

```
<div th:each="custSection : ${course.sections}" class="panel panel-primary">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label col-xs-12 col-md-2" for="sectionsName">Section Name:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5">
        <div class="control-label pull-left label-input" id="_sectionsName"><span id="_sectionsNameText" th:text="${custSection.sectionName}" style="margin-right: 1em;"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" id="_sectionsNameEditIcon"></span>
      </div>
        <div class="input-group">
          <input class="form-control hidden" id="sectionName" name="sectionName" type="text" th:value="${custSection.sectionName}" maxlength="60" />
          <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameOK"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></span>
          <span class="btn btn-default input-group-addon hidden" id="sectionsNameCancel"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div th:each="lesson : ${custSection.lessons}" class="panel-body">
    <a th:href="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons/{lessonId}(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id},lessonId=${lesson.id})}" th:text="${lesson.title}"></a>
  </div>
  <form th:action="@{{courseId}/sections/{sectionId}/lessons(courseId=${course.id},sectionId=${custSection.id})}" method="post">
    <button class="btn btn-default">Add a Lesson</button>
  </form>
</div>
```